# Sign a message with EdDSA algorithm in Javascript to get JWT

Tags: javascript, jwt, uint8array, ed25519, eddsa

I need to get JWT with EdDSA algorithm to be able to use an API. I have the private key to sign the message and I could do that with PHP with the next library: https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt  (you can see the example with EdDSA at README). Now I need to do the same in JS but I didn't find the way to get JWT with a given secret key (encoded base 64) like that (only an example is not the real secretKey):

```
const secretKey = Dm2xriMD6riJagld4WCA6zWqtuWh40UzT/ZKO0pZgtHATOt0pGw90jG8BQHCE3EOjiCkFR2/gaW6JWi+3nZp8A==
```

I tried a lot of libraries like jose, js-nacl, crypto, libsodium, etc. And I am really close to get the JWT with libsodium library, now I attach the code:

```js
const base64url = require("base64url");
const _sodium = require("libsodium-wrappers");
const moment = require("moment");

const getJWT = async () => {
  await _sodium.ready;
  const sodium = _sodium;

  const privateKey =
    "Dm2xriMD6riJagld4WCA6zWqtuWh40UzT/ZKO0pZgtHATOt0pGw90jG8BQHCE3EOjiCkFR2/gaW6JWi+3nZp8A==";
  const payload = {
    iss: "test",
    aud: "test.com",
    iat: 1650101178,
    exp: 1650101278,
    sub: "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123"
  };
  const { msg, keyAscii} = encode(payload, privateKey, "EdDSA");
  const signature = sodium.crypto_sign_detached(msg, keyDecoded); //returns Uint8Array(64)
  //Here is the problem.
};
```

```js
const encode = (payload, key, alg) => {
  const header = {
    typ: "JWT",
    alg //'EdDSA'
  };
  const headerBase64URL = base64url(JSON.stringify(header));
  const payloadBase64URL = base64url(JSON.stringify(payload));
  const headerAndPayloadBase64URL = `${headerBase64URL}.${payloadBase64URL}`;
  const keyAscii= Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("ascii");
  return {headerAndPayloadBase64URL , keyAscii}
};
```

The problem is in the sodium.crypto_sign_detached function because it returns an Uint8Array(64) signature and and I need the JWT like that:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiYXVkIjoidGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAxMDExNzgsImV4cCI6MTY1MDEwMTI3OCwic3ViIjoiMTIzNDU2NzgtMTIzNC0xMjM0LTEyMzQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzIn0.f7WG_02UKljrMeVVOTNNBAGxtLXJUT_8QAnujNhomV18Pn5cU-0lHRgVlmRttOlqI7Iol_fHut3C4AOXxDGnAQ
```

How can I change the Uint8Array(64) to get the signature in a right format to get the JWT? I tried with base64, base64url, hex, text, ascii, etc and the final JWT is not valid (because the signature is wrong).
If you compare my code with the code that I mentioned with PHP is very similar but the function sodium.crypto_sign_detached returns Uint8Array(64) at JS library and the same function in PHP returns an string and I can get the token.
Or maybe there a way to adapt my given private key for use in other library (like crypto or jose where I received an error for the private key format)
Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just import the `Uint8Array` with `Buffer.from()` into a buffer and convert the buffer with `base64url()` into a Base64url string? This string would then only have to be concatenated with `headerAndPayloadBase64URL` (with a dot as separator).

Comment: I tried with 

  const newKey = base64url(Buffer.from(keyDecoded));
  const signature = sodium.crypto_sign_detached(msg, newKey);

But I received an error: TypeError: invalid privateKey length

Comment: Why do you create a new key? Your problem was the signature as `Uint8Array`, at least according to your description. My suggestion was to convert this signature to Base64url and concatenate `headerAndPayloadBase64URL` with this Base64url signature to get a JWT in the desired format, s. [here](https://jwt.io/introduction), sec. *What is the JSON Web Token structure?*

Comment: Now I get a signature that looks like the signature I got from PHP function (is not the same), but the final JWT is invalid.

Comment: I changed the moment() value for moment().unix() and now it's ok that. I can check the token because I have an API when I set the token the API must work if the token is valid. I saw that when I decoded the key here: Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("ascii") it returned a different value than PHP function (base64_encode) so I think that is the problem. With PHP base64_encode function I received: .3K��yd-}ڟv7qr7vgd>  and with JS I received a different string h↑nz-6+cj<.$d3K-▲]@6yd6-☼[}→Z▼vgvgd.>   . How is it possible?

Comment: These are consistent keys for the NodeJS side (Base64): private: Dm2xriMD6riJagld4WCA6zWqtuWh40UzT/ZKO0pZgtHATOt0pGw90jG8BQHCE3EOjiCkFR2/gaW6JWi+3nZp8A== and public: wEzrdKRsPdIxvAUBwhNxDo4gpBUdv4GluiVovt52afA=. Post the JWT of the NodeJS and PHP code for this. You should use a constant value for `iat` in *both* codes. Analogously for `exp`. This makes a comparison of both signatures easier (Ed25519 is deterministic).

Comment: @Topaco I edited the original post with the payload test and private key, thank you

Comment: If I changed Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("ascii") for Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("binary") I received an error in sodium.crypto_sign_detached function: TypeError: invalid privateKey length, with those values that you sent me I have this JWT in PHP: 
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiYXVkIjoidGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAxMDExNzgsImV4cCI6MTY1MDEwMTI3OCwic3ViIjoiMTIzNDU2NzgtMTIzNC0xMjM0LTEyMzQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzIn0.f7WG_02UKljrMeVVOTNNBAGxtLXJUT_8QAnujNhomV18Pn5cU-0lHRgVlmRttOlqI7Iol_fHut3C4AOXxDGnAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the posted NodeJS code there are the following issues:

- `crypto_sign_detached()` returns the signature as a `Uint8Array`, which can be imported with `Buffer.from()` and converted to a Base64 string with `base64url()`.
- Concatenating `headerAndPayloadBase64URL` and the Base64url encoded signature with a `.` as separator gives the JWT you are looking for.
- The raw private key must not be decoded with `'ascii'`, as this generally corrupts the data. Instead, it should simply be handled as buffer. Note: If for some reason a conversion to a string is required, use `'binary'` as encoding, which produces a byte string (however, this is not an option with `crypto_sign_detached()` as this function expects a buffer).

With these changes, the following NodeJS code results:

```js
const _sodium = require('libsodium-wrappers');
const base64url = require("base64url");

const getJWT = async () => {  
    await _sodium.ready;
    const sodium = _sodium;
    const privateKey = "Dm2xriMD6riJagld4WCA6zWqtuWh40UzT/ZKO0pZgtHATOt0pGw90jG8BQHCE3EOjiCkFR2/gaW6JWi+3nZp8A==";
    const payload = {
        iss: "test",
        aud: "test.com",
        iat: 1650101178,
        exp: 1650101278,
        sub: "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789123"
     };  
     const {headerAndPayloadBase64URL, keyBuf} = encode(payload, privateKey, "EdDSA");
     const signature = sodium.crypto_sign_detached(headerAndPayloadBase64URL, keyBuf); 
     const signatureBase64url = base64url(Buffer.from(signature));
     console.log(`${headerAndPayloadBase64URL}.${signatureBase64url}`) // eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiYXVkIjoidGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAxMDExNzgsImV4cCI6MTY1MDEwMTI3OCwic3ViIjoiMTIzNDU2NzgtMTIzNC0xMjM0LTEyMzQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzIn0.f7WG_02UKljrMeVVOTNNBAGxtLXJUT_8QAnujNhomV18Pn5cU-0lHRgVlmRttOlqI7Iol_fHut3C4AOXxDGnAQ
};

const encode = (payload, key, alg) => {
    const header = {
        typ: "JWT",
        alg //'EdDSA'
    };
    const headerBase64URL = base64url(JSON.stringify(header));
    const payloadBase64URL = base64url(JSON.stringify(payload));
    const headerAndPayloadBase64URL = `${headerBase64URL}.${payloadBase64URL}`;
    const keyBuf = Buffer.from(key, "base64");
    return {headerAndPayloadBase64URL, keyBuf};
};

getJWT();
```

Test:
Since Ed25519 is deterministic, the NodeJS code can be checked by comparing both JWTs: If, as in the above NodeJS code, the same header and payload are used as in the PHP code, the same signature and thus the *same* JWT is generated as by the PHP code, namely:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFZERTQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiYXVkIjoidGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2NTAxMDExNzgsImV4cCI6MTY1MDEwMTI3OCwic3ViIjoiMTIzNDU2NzgtMTIzNC0xMjM0LTEyMzQtMTIzNDU2Nzg5MTIzIn0.f7WG_02UKljrMeVVOTNNBAGxtLXJUT_8QAnujNhomV18Pn5cU-0lHRgVlmRttOlqI7Iol_fHut3C4AOXxDGnAQ
```

which shows that the NodeJS code works.

---

Note that instead of the `moment` package, `Date.now()` could be used. This will return the time in milliseconds, so the value has to be divided by 1000, e.g. `Math.round(Date.now()/1000)`, but saves a dependency.