# Base64 Decode - Javascript - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, base64, decode, encode

I have the next string with base 64 encoded:

```
aJjueq22q2O202ZzZdpjPO6Cr32p0cc22jeaceupcjd2Z2SuPg2J6rwupOQzS62e3cC2eWS2gC2P232a2p925w==
```

When I decoded with base64_decode function in PHP I received the next string:

```
$key = base64_decode($key);
.3K��yd-}ڟv7qr7vgd>
```

But in JS I did the next:

```
const key = Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("ascii");
```

And I received a different decoded string:

```
h↑nz-6+cj<.$d3K-▲]@6yd6-☼[}→Z▼vgvgd.>
```

How is it possible? I need to get a string like the first (PHP)

Comment: In both cases you show, neither ends up as "ascii". So the PHP way results in byte code. And your js attempt wants to make it into "ascii". It's *not* ascii when decoded, otherwise it would be "readable" a lil bit?

Comment: `base64_encode` doesn't decode, it encodes. `base64_decode` decodes.

Comment: the base64 string is 88 characters long or 86 without padding. That's 512 bits or 64 bytes that are encoded in it. Why do you consider a wrongly to ASCII or UTF-8 decoded string of 19 characters including placeholder for unprintable characters as a correct result? What do you even expect to find in it?

Comment: The only that I know is the decode that PHP does is working well, and I need to get the same decode in JS, how can I do? Thank you!

Comment: Further, when I base64-decode in Notepad++, I get `h¶«c¶Ӧseڣ<}©ч6ڷq멲7vgd®>
꼮¤䳋­݀¶yd¶-۽ڟv`, and when I decode in one of them online tools, I get `hîz­¶«c¶ÓfseÚc<î¯}©ÑÇ6Ú7që©r7vgd®>
ê¼.¤ä3K­ÝÀ¶yd¶-Û}Úvç`. And when I save the binary data into a file, and view with HxD, I get `h˜îz­¶«c¶ÓfseÚc<î‚¯}©ÑÇ6Ú7šqë©r7vgd®>
‰ê¼.¤ä3K­žÝÀ¶yd¶€-Û}šÚŸvç` as the "decoded text". What do we learn from this? That binary data isn't meant to be viewed as an ASCII representation or coerced into ASCII. In JS, convert to blob?

Comment: @MatiasWajnman How do you define "working well", when you get a more or less random result of 19 characters after wrongly decoding 64 byte binary data to a 'readable' string?

Comment: Im trying to adapt a PHP code in JS code and I have a lots of problems. Yesterday I created other post to talk about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877860/sign-a-message-with-eddsa-algorithm-in-javascript-to-get-jwt) . Today I tried again to find the problem and I saw that the output of base64_decode($key) in PHP is different than the output of my JS code key = Buffer.from(key, "base64").toString("ascii"). I understand that way is wrong but how can I get the same output of base64_decode($key) in JS? Maybe the string representation wasn't a good idea.

Comment: If you want to compare the result of decoded binary data, you need to compare the actual binary data, not its (lossy) ASCII string representations. [Create a BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) in JS, save it, and compare it to the binary data decoded in PHP (either fetching the file contents in PHP and comparing, or using a hex editor) to verify that the (binary data of the) outcomes match.

Comment: The JavaScript counterpart to the PHP byte string would most closely be achieved with `.toString('binary')` instead of `.toString('ascii')`. Arbitrary binary data is usually corrupted when output to the console (charset encodings) and often displayed differently (different encodings and fonts). For comparison, a binary-to-text encoding like *hex* is best, e.g. `print(bin2hex($key))` or `console.log(Buffer.from(key, 'binary').toString('hex'))`. Regarding your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71877860/9014097): handle the key as buffer rather than string for compatibility reasons.